# Exported layer shows zero geometries using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

QGIS Desktop application (version X) was used to query a layer and then export result geometries as shapefile. QGIS Desktop application (3.10.12-A Coruña) is used to open the shapefile and view geometries but QGIS shows no features and says that feature count is zero.

Exported shapefile is > 1GB so there must be at least one geometry exported right?

Comment: Please provide more details about the queried layer, the query and how you exported the data.

Comment: Do u see at least some features in the attribute table ?